# Ink Smart Contract call Error

Tags: ink, smart-contract, error

I am deploying an ink! smart contract to a local network, but when I tried to call any function from it i have this error:

```
> { Err: { Module: { index: '8', error: '0x02000000' } } }
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the error and why?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your runtime file? To understand what the error: `{ Err: { Module: { index: '8', error: '0x02000000' } } }` means we have to check the runtime code in your Substrate node.

The `index number` is the index of the pallet in the runtime from which the error originated. The `error` is the index of that pallet's errors (in hex) which is the exact one we're looking for. Both of these indices start counting from 0.

For example if you are running the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) we can see that the index 8 refers to pallet Contracts ([see code here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L398)). If we go now to the [pallet Contracts code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/) we can see that the error in the position `0x02000000` (2 in hex) is OutOfGas ([see the code here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L901)).

Answer (score 1):

You can dry-run the transaction and receive more human-friendly errors, as far as I remember using https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ you will always see dry-run result before submitting the tx